# What is this screwdriver-like object?

Tags: props, life-2017

Without giving anything away, in the film Life (2017), Hugh Derry uses what appears to be a screwdriver-like cattleprod on a *"low voltage"* setting.

**Does this device have a name?**

Comment: Sounds like a cattle prod to me...

Comment: There's a [tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Human-Cattle-Prod/) for making a DIY human cattle prod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script describes it as a "***glass wand"*** with an ***"electric tip***".

> Derry picks up a GLASS WAND, roughly eight inches long, with a
>   remotely activated ELECTRIC TIP.
>
> **ADAMS:** *Come on in. We're shocking the monkey.*
>
> BRAGG pulls herself into Harmony from Zvezda.
>
> Kendo slides a slider on the touch-pad. The tip of the glass wand
>   SPARKS subtly with buzzing electricity. Derry lifts the wand to the
>   creature. Aims it at one of its stubby appendages. And very, very
>   gently TOUCHES it. *Bzzt.*